# No bottom plate

Tags: framing

I have an old house. Upstairs is like a loft with gable roof. I took all the old drywall out and there is not bottom plate anywhere around the whole perimeter. Studs are just connected to the old wood floor 20”off. Should I put a plate down or what? In between all studs for blocking/nailers I am going with shiplap on walls.

Comment: What do you mean by "perimeter"? A room's perimeter or the house's perimeter? The critical question is whether these walls are load bearing. Around a gabled roofed house's perimeter, usually two of the walls are load bearing.

Comment: Are these little walls in the loft space to hide the low headroom areas?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It's an old house, presumably, it's been standing all this time. If your ceiling is sagging or the walls are bowing, then we'd need to know that, but you'd _really_ need to talk to a local engineer to find a solution.